# mt.exe : general error c101008d: Failed to write the updated manifest to the resource of file ... Access is denied

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I often have this problem even when I build a new C++ project and try to build a release file.

I use Visual studio 2008. One thing that may cause this problem is my code is saved on the server disk, not on local hard disk.

mt.exe : general error c101008d: Failed to write the updated manifest to the resource of file "..\Release\PGTS_version17C.exe". The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Anyone know how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 52):

If you are embedding a manifest file, your anti-virus program may lock and scan your exe file before embedding the manifest.

I recommend disabling anti-virus from reading your DEBUG and RELEASE output folders.

Comment: For the sake of completeness http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH196178

Comment: You are a lifesaver! +1, that helped me out a lot.

Comment: Even WindowsDefender seems to stay in this way.

Comment: I added the folders to the list of exclusions, http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5924-windows-defender-exclusions-add-remove-windows-10-a.html

Comment: In case you have Windows Defender, use these steps and turn off Real-time Protection: http://www.wisecleaner.com/how-to/119-how-to-turn-off-windows-defender-in-windows-10.html

Answer (score 16):

Go to `Debug` and/or `Release` folder(s), right click and unset, recursively, the Read-Only property.

Found this tip in the [MSDN Community](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68ff263a-186a-4c91-be19-404482b1fdd0/general-error-c101008d-failed-to-write-the-updated-manifest-to-the-resource-of-file-access-is?forum=Vsexpressvc) and solved my problem!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: That wasnt the problem, as the error still occurred.  It appears to be some intermittent issue - sometimes the compile works, sometimes it doesn't ... showed up once system was upgraded to Windows 10 (with whatever payload my company used along with that image).  Never an issue under my old Windows 7 system.

Answer (score 14):

It it's not a permissions or actual file access problem (AV)...

You can add a flag to make the compiler check the validity of the manifest.

This validation will fix the problem so you'll never have to rebuild it again.
This is very important for anyone who's running an actual Build-Machine or automatic buildscript where you don't want to manually interfere:

Add this flag:
**Project properties -> Configuration Properties -> Manifest Tool -> Command Line -> Additional options:**

```
/validate_manifest
```

Comment: That solved my issue. Typically a `Build-Machine` or `automatic buildscript` as you said.

Answer (score 8):

Funny enough I had the exact same error and a "rebuild" on the whole project solved it.

Answer (score 5):

disabling the Anti-Virus worked for me.

Comment: Any particular brand of Antivirus?

Comment: If avast antivirus is installed, then this issue occures.

Answer (score 4):

If you need not generate Manifest file, just set it off it will resolve the problem.

> Goto Project(right click)
>
> properties
>
> Linker
>
> Manifest Files
>
> Generate Manifest
>
> change it Yes to No

It resolve the problem for me on *VS2008* without disabling Anti-virus. ;)

Enjoy :)

Comment: Worked for me on VS2010 as well

Answer (score 3):

Open visual studio 2010 as "Run as administrator" and Rebuild again.

Answer (score 3):

I worked around this with a "wrapper" program for `mt.exe`, one that reran it until it succeeded.  Save the following code as `mt-wrapper.cpp`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>

// Build from a Visual Studio Command Prompt with "cl /O2 /Gy /Femt.exe mt-wrapper.cpp"

int __cdecl wmain(int argc, WCHAR **argv, WCHAR **env)
{
    // Stop outputting text.
    fclose(stdout);
    fclose(stderr);

    // Run the original mt.exe, which has been renamed to mt-orig.exe .
    for (;;)
    {
        // Try to run the original mt.
        intptr_t iStatus = _wspawnve(_P_WAIT, L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Bin\\mt-orig.exe", argv + 1, env);
        if (iStatus == 0)
            break;

        // Try again, after a short wait.
        ::Sleep(100);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Build this program, go to your `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin` folder, rename the old `mt.exe` to `mt-orig.exe` (and the `mt.exe.config` to `mt-orig.exe.config`), and put this wrapper program in there as `mt.exe`. Now, when you build, it will retry running the original `mt.exe` until it succeeds.

Oddly, MSBuild doesn't seem to check for a zero status when deciding that `mt.exe` has succeeded — it seems to look for error messages written to stdout/stderr.  So this program closes both of those before spawning the original `mt.exe`. Anyone feeling industrious can apply the advice found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14149200) to save the output of the successful run of the original `mt.exe`, and output it to stdout/stderr.

Comment: I have used your code as base for project on [github](https://github.com/BilyakA/mt-wrapper). Hope you won't mind.

Comment: @ElDorado: Of course I don't mind! Thanks for the compliment!

Comment: Thank you for this solution! 

Note: with Windows 10 / VS 2019 I had to change the path to:
`C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\10.0.19041.0\\x86\\mt-orig.exe`
There is also a parallel file:
`...\\x64\\mt-orig.exe`

Now my compilation is stuck on:
`Embedding manifest...`

From this I gather that your code works as intended, but doesn't solve the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Disable AV
2. Temporary rename your exe so it doesn't contain any of the words UAC magic words (install, setup, patch, upgrade)
3. make sure you have write permissions
4. use mt command to inject the manifest
5. rename back your exe

Answer (score 1):

In my case none of the suggestions presented here worked. I am using Ninja build with VS 2019, and build fails randomly in only Jenkins. Disable manifest is not an option in our case. As a workaround I disable manifest during link stage, however added a custom target with POST_BUILD step to embed manifest using mt.exe.

## disable manifest during link stage

```
target_link_options(target_name PRIVATE /MANIFEST:NO)
```

## add post build step. change #1 (used for exe) to #2 if using dll

```
add_custom_command(TARGET target_name POST_BUILD
                COMMAND mt.exe -manifest manifest_file -outputresource:$<TARGET_FILE:target_name>;#1
                COMMENT "Adding custom manifest on target_name" 
                VERBATIM)
```

With above workaround no failure in Jenkins server now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Hudson/Jenkins to create releases restarting it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by stopping and disabling the 'Timing Service' (part of FireEye)

Answer (score 0):

If your project is stored in Dropbox, you have to quit Dropbox to build. This is also an issue when using Unreal Engine.

Comment: If this is an already known issue, could you maybe provide a link to where it is documented?

Comment: I dont know if this is officially documented anywhere; but I found out by asking on an Unreal Engine facebook group, and got this tip from someone. 
Dropbox makes for some strange behaviour when saving, not sure exactly what. I only use github now.