# How to communicate between a android process and a windows process?

Tags: android, c++, windows, adb

Now I use adb command line to do this,but I can't get the details of the adb tool's work result.Is there another way to communicate with an android app on windows? Or I can use adb tools more direct like use a dll,just call its API, instead of executing the adb.exe with command line?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/205381). What are you trying to accomplish? How does adb fail to meet your requirements?

Comment: @IInspectable just want to send datas to an android application from my windows c++ program and get the details of adb.exe's handle result,some informations like errcode and error description.

Comment: You just repeated, what we already know, but didn't answer the inquiry, why launching `adb.exe` fails to meet your requirements.

Comment: @IInspectable For example,I use "shellexecute" function to execute adb.exe and the command is "adb devices",In cmd window,I can see the list of devices and which is unauthorized or there is no device connected.But how could I know about this in my code,the shellexecute function just return a code about the execution.

Comment: That's a different question, and it has been [asked and answered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14147138/1889329) before.