# MSVC++ error during the linking process after the inclusion of a new cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, manifest

I have added a new cpp file to the existing MSVC++ project (it generates an exe), After adding  the particular cpp file (which contains a new main function) i encountered a following error

```
mt.exe : general error c101008a: Failed to save the updated manifest to the file ".\myproject.dir\Debug\myproject.exe.embed.manifest". The parameter is incorrect.
```

If i get rid of this newly added file, then the project compiles as it did before the inclusion of the new file,

What can be the reason for this error?

Comment: is your code have two main functions after adding this new file ?

Comment: nope, previous main function has been commented out

Comment: Try to Clean solution and rebuild it

Comment: And make sure all instances of MyProject.exe have been stopped. Use Task Manager (CTRL+SHIFT+ESC) to validate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mt.exe : general error c101008d: Failed to write the updated manifest to the resource of file ... Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775406/mt-exe-general-error-c101008d-failed-to-write-the-updated-manifest-to-the-res)

Answer (score 2):

Clean the project and rebuild again works for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a permissions or actual file access problem (AV)...

You can add a flag to make the compiler check the validity of the manifest.

This validation will fix the problem so you'll never have to rebuild it again.
This is very important for anyone who's running an actual Build-Machine or automatic buildscript where you don't want to manually interfere:

Add this flag:
**Project properties -> Configuration Properties -> Manifest Tool -> Command Line -> Additional options:**

```
/validate_manifest
```