# How can I set the MSVC embed manifest linker setting using CMake?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, manifest, qt6

I am trying to build qt6 on windows, however, it report error while `cmake --build .`:

```
cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\un-setup\cmake\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_dll --intdir=qtbase\src\gui\CMakeFiles\Gui.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WINDOW~4\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WINDOW~4\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1430~1.307\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\Gui.rsp  /out:qtbase\bin\Qt6Guid.dll /implib:qtbase\lib\Qt6Guid.lib /pdb:qtbase\bin\Qt6Guid.pdb /dll /version:6.4 /machine:x64 /debug  -DYNAMICBASE -NXCOMPAT -LARGEADDRESSAWARE  && cd ."
MT: command "C:\PROGRA~2\WINDOW~4\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\mt.exe /nologo /manifest qtbase\bin\Qt6Guid.dll.manifest /outputresource:qtbase\bin\Qt6Guid.dll;#2" failed (exit code 0x1f) with the following output:

mt.exe : general error c101008d: Failed to write the updated manifest to the resource of file "qtbase\bin\Qt6Guid.dll".
```

I searched that, the reason is target dll (Qt6Guid.dll) is locked by some other program, probably virus software (source: [mt.exe : general error c101008d: Failed to write the updated manifest to the resource of file ... Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3775406/11107541)). So I have tried:

- I disabled my only virsus software windows defender in my computer. It still report the same error.
- Use processmonitor to monitor the whole build process, and I still failed to find the which one locks the dll file.

I still find that there is another resolution: in VS GUI, set embed manifest to no.
However I am using cmake, then **How can I pass the setting (no embed manifest) through configure**?
Currently my configure option is (in build dir under Qt6 source code)

```
../configure.bat -prefix d:\Qt6
```

If it's not possible to set the embed manifest setting to `NO` using CMake, how can I disable windows defender totally?

Answer (score 1):

If you are indeed okay with the consequences of setting `NO` for the embed manifest setting to work around this issue, I'm pretty sure the say to do it with CMake is to just use the commandline linker flag: `/MANIFEST:NO`.

Based on the types of targets you want this to apply for, use one or multiple of the following: [`CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS.html), [`CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS.html), or [`CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS.html).

Since the issue is tied to your specific machine, I'd set this as a cache variable via commandline using [the `-D` flag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D) in your configuration command instead of hardcoding it into your CMakeLists.txt file with `target_link_options` or `add_link_options`.

Obviously it would be better to find out what's causing the issue, but luckily for me, you didn't ask for that :) (and I don't think anyone can figure that out for you without access to your machine)

Related docs:

- [Understanding manifest generation for C/C++ programs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/understanding-manifest-generation-for-c-cpp-programs)
- [`/MANIFEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifest-create-side-by-side-assembly-manifest)